# I got Error An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, blazor

i'm newly learning ASP.net Core and i got this error :

[image]

I have been searching the solution i internet but didn't get any result. Can anyone help me? this is my code:

Details.cshtml

```
@model SixthApp.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Customer</h4>
    <p>@ViewData["data"]</p>

    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerId)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerId)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

this is detail method in CustomerController.cs

```
        public IActionResult Details(int? Id)
        {
            var DataCustomer = _conn.tabel_customer.Where(c => c.CustomerId == Id).ToList();

            return View(DataCustomer);
        }
```

Comment: Always post error messages as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     public IActionResult Details(int? Id)
>     {
>         var DataCustomer = _conn.tabel_customer.Where(c => c.CustomerId == Id).ToList();
>
>         return View(DataCustomer);
>     }
> ```

The type your view needs is a `model`, and what you return to the view in your action is a `list`

Try below code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? Id)
    {
        var DataCustomer =  await _conn.tabel_customer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == Id);

        return View(DataCustomer);
    }
```

Comment: It works, thanks very much. Any way, why using `async Task<IActionResult>`  for declare `Details` method?

Comment: @RizalMaulana  You are welcome:)        Beacuse  when using `FirstOrDefaultAsync ` we should use `async Task<IActionResult> `

Answer (score 1):

You are returning list of objects, and view expects a single object.
You should, either change your controller to something like this, to return single object:

```
public IActionResult Details(int? Id)
{
    var DataCustomer = _conn.tabel_customer.Where(c => c.CustomerId == Id).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(DataCustomer);
}
```

or change model to `@model IEnumerable<SixthApp.Models.Customer>` and loop trough it on a view to show all objects you got from controller....

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i got new errorr  :

`Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<Customer>' does not contain a definition for 'Address' and no accessible extension method 'Address' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Customer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

may i know why this happen?